# unable to display listweek and listday buttons fullcalendar angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm working with fullcalendar AngularJS. Somehow I'm unable to fetch the `listWeek` and `listDay` buttons on my calendar header. unable to understand where I might have gone wrong.

this is the config var

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    height: 500,
    eventCalendar: {
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'listWeek listDay'
        },
        views: {
            listDay: { buttonText: 'Day' },
            listWeek: { buttonText: 'Week' }

        },
        defaultView: 'listWeek',
        timezone: "local",
        navLinks: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        hiddenDays: [0, 6],
        allDaySlot:  false,
        minTime: "08:00:00",
        maxTime: "17:00:00",
        eventOverlap: false,
        selectOverlap: false
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `views` option and add the `buttonText`this will resolve your problem.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
        height: 500,
        eventCalendar: {
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'listWeek listDay'
            },
            buttonText: {
                listDay: 'Day',
                listWeek 'Week'
            },
            defaultView: 'listWeek',
            timezone: "local",
            navLinks: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            hiddenDays: [0, 6],
            allDaySlot:  false,
            minTime: "08:00:00",
            maxTime: "17:00:00",
            eventOverlap: false,
            selectOverlap: false
       }
   }
};
```

Otherwise you have to add more options in your `views` in order to work for you something like this, but this way is used for custom views

```
views: {
    listDay: { 
        type:'list', 
        duration:{
            days:1
        }, 
        buttonText: 'Day' 
    },
    listWeek: { 
        type:'list', 
        duration:{
            days:7
        }, 
        buttonText: 'Week' 
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have included the print.css and set it's media attribute to "print", i.e.; media="print".

That may correct your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

buttonText :

{

today: 'Today',

month: 'Month',

week: 'Week',

day: 'Day',

listMonth: 'List Month',

listYear: 'List Year',

listWeek: 'List Week,

listDay: 'List Day'

}

here->https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonText